# One to Zero-or-One relation via fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, fluent

I want to define the following model with fluent api.

[image]

So I wrote this model

```
public class Entity1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
}
```

And this mapping

```
public class Entity1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity1>
{
    public Entity1Map()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Entity1");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    }
}

public class Entity2Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity2>
{
    public Entity2Map()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Entity2");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        // Relationships          
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Entity1)
            .WithOptional(t => t.Entity2);
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward. I then generate the migrations with the `Add-Migration` command.

This is where I get confused. Cause the generated tables doesn't look as I would have expected.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Entity1",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Entity2",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Entity1", t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```

First off I would have expected a nullable foreign key in Entity1. But this `.ForeignKey("dbo.Entity1", t => t.Id)` makes little sense to me, it's defining a foreign key to `Entity1` with the `Id` from it's own table. Isn't that a self-reference?

Another problem is that I cannot seem to put `.HasForeignKey()` on the relation. In case I wanted to have the foreign key represented in the model, like it's done with One-to-Many relations.

Comment: Can you doublecheck the code you posted? Is Entity2 supposed to map to table Entity1 as well?

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998863/one-to-one-relationship-in-cf-entity-framework-using-mapping) is what you are looking for?

Comment: I think the problem is that I had misunderstood where EF puts the foreign keys in 1:0..1 relation. The Id of the 0..1  (entity2) table is primary while also being the foreign key instead of placing it in the other (entity1) table. Both approaches has pros and cons. However it does put a double index on this Id key which I believe to be a bug. Cause the primary key is already an index, so there's no need to index it again.